# How can I store the substring from the strrchr function?

Tags: c

I'm writing a program for a class this semester and I need to ask the user to enter a string which is supposed to be a path to a certain `.wav` audio file called `ts9_mono.wav`.

a possible path string for this audio file could look like: **"C:/classes/ts9_mono.wav"**

After that, I need to check if the file that is specified in the path is indeed a `.wav` file. For the assignment, I am told that I need to look at the last period in the path string and look at the last 3-4 characters after that period.

I believe the best way to do this is to use `strrchr()`, for example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char path[200]; //this char array is for storing the path string
    scanf("%s", &path); //let's pretend the user enters C:/classes/ts9_mono.wav

    printf("%s", strrchr(path, '.'));
}
```

Now the output to the screen would be: **.wav**

My plan for this part of the assignment is to somehow store the **.wav** substring given by the `strrchr` function and compare that to another char array which will store `".wav"` to check if they are the same.

I know that `strrchr` returns the address of the character if it can be found in the string, but I do not understand how I can use that pointer to do what I plan to do above.

Comment: which language? C or C++? they are not the same

Comment: Assign it to a variable, perhaps?

Comment: Or just don't print it, but do what you actually want to do: compare: `if (!strcmp(strrchr(path, '.'), ".wav")) ...` (If you are sure the full stop will always be there. If not, test first and *then* compare.)

Comment: Wow, I totally forgot how strcmp worked. You are completely right @usr2564301! I forgot strcmp returns 0 if the two values were equal. In my head, I kept thinking that if the two values were equal the return would be 1. I actually tried to do what you just suggested before asking this question, but because of this misconception I was wondering why I wasn't obtaining the value of 1.

Comment: Do you want a proper answer, with full details? Or are you good for the moment?

Comment: Nope, you don't have to do that, I'm all set now. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @KevinNguyen: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to store the result of strchr in a char pointer (char*) and then do strcmp to see if the input is what you want.
Example:

```
char path[200];
char* result = NULL;
if (scanf("%199s", path)) != 1) // as per the comment from 'chqrlie for yellow blockquotes'
    return 1;

result = strrchr(path, '.');

if (!result)
{
    //There is no '.'
    printf("There is no dot!");
}
else
{
    if (strcmp(result, ".wav") == 0)
     {
        printf("The value ends with .wav!");
     }
}
```

Comment: @chqrlieforyellowblockquotes Thanks for pointing out the mistakes, i was just trying to give him a rough idea of how to do it so i didn't bother to make anything pretty.